# Does the $0$ element of a stalk have to $0$ only at the point, or does it also have to be $0$ in a neighborhood containing the point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

For a prime ideal $p$ in Spec $A$, consider the $0$ element of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_p$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the structure sheaf.

If $f$ is equivalent to the $0$ element of the stalk, then does it have to be $0$ in a neighborhood containing $p$, or does it have to be $0$ only at $p$? I thought that it has to be $0$ in a neighborhood, but reading a proof in Hartshorne is making me think otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open subset of ${\rm Spec}(A)$ containing the point $\mathfrak p$, and let $f$ be a section in $\mathcal O(U)$. For $f$ to vanish in the stalk $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$, we need $f$ to vanish as an element of the localisation $A_{\mathfrak p}$. That's all the definition requires.

However, if it is the case that $f$ vanishes in the stalk $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$, then it is easy to show that there must exist an open neighbourhood $V \subset U$ of $\mathfrak p$ such that $f$ vanish in the stalks $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$ for all $\mathfrak q \in V$.

Some examples:

- $A = k[x]$, $\mathfrak p = (x)$, $f = 0$. This $f$ vanishes in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p} = A_{\mathfrak p}$. But $\mathfrak p$ is not the only point where $f$ vanishes: $f$ also vanishes in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$ for all $\mathfrak q \in {\rm Spec}(A)$.
- $A = k[x,y]/(xy)$, $\mathfrak p = (x - 1)$, $f=y$. (You can think of the space as the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes.) $f$ vanishes in the localisation $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p} = A_{\mathfrak p}$, by virtue of the fact that $xf$ is zero in $A$, and $x \notin \mathfrak p$. But $\mathfrak p$ is not the only point where $f$ vanishes: $f$ also vanishes in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$ for all $\mathfrak q \in D(x) \subset {\rm Spec}(A)$, where $D(x)$ is the open subset of ${\rm Spec}(A)$ consisting of the prime ideals in $A$ that do not contain $x$.

For the general case, suppose $A$ is a ring, $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, and $f = g/h$ is an element of $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p} = A_{\mathfrak p}$ (with $g \in A$ and $h \in A \setminus \mathfrak p$). If $f$ vanishes as an element of $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p} = A_{\mathfrak p}$, then there exists an element $e \in A \setminus \mathfrak p$ such that $eg$ vanishes as an element of $A$. So $f$ also vanishes in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$ for all $\mathfrak q$ in the open neighbourhood $V = D(e)\cap D(h) \subset {\rm Spec}(A)$. (In fact, $f$ also vanishes as a section in $\mathcal O(V)$.)

By the way, if you don't want to fiddle around with localisations, there is a purely sheaf-theoretic way of handling this. The stalk $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$ is the set of equivalence classes $[(U, f)]$ (with $\mathfrak p \in U$), where $(U_1, f_1) \sim (U_2, f_2)$ iff there exists an open $V \subset U_1 \cap U_2$ containing $\mathfrak p$ such that $f_1|_{V} = f_2|_{V}$. The zero element of the stalk $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$ is the equivalence class of $({\rm Spec}(A), 0)$. So if a section $f$ in $\mathcal O(U)$ restricts to the zero element in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$, then there must exist an open neighbourhood $V \subset U$ containing $\mathfrak p$ such that $0|_V = f|_V$. But then, $f$ restricts to the zero element in $\mathcal O(V)$, and so, $f$ restricts to the zero element in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak q}$ for every $\mathfrak q \in V$.

Comment: In your second example I cannot understand what you mean by writing $A_p$. In general for a ring $A$ and a prime ideal $p$, the ring $A_p$ is the localization of $A$ at the multiplicatively set $A-p$. But in your example the set $A-p$ contains also $0+(xy)$ which is the product of $x+(xy)$ and $y+(xy)$ since both of them are in $A-p$.

Also your example looks like the example just before exercise 3.2.L on Vakil's Rising Sea notes. But in there he localized $A$ at the multiplicative set ${1,x,x^2...}$.

Comment: Well in fact, $\mathfrak{p}=(x-1)$ is not an ideal of $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$ since $(xy)$ is not contained in $(x-1)$.

Comment: And finally I believe that the OP asked something more essential than that, which also led me to find this question and I have a similar question in mind: Consider $(,\mathcal{F})$ a locally ringed space and assume that for a global section $f\in \mathcal{F}(X)$, its stalk $f_p$ at a point $p\in X$ is contained in the maximal ideal $m_p$ of the stalk $\mathcal{F}_p$. Does this imply that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ such that $f|_U=0$?

Comment: It's been ages since I've done any math, but I rereading this, it seems that my $p$ is the principal ideal in $A$ generated by the element $x-1+(xy)$. This is a prime ideal, so you can take the localisation. Also, $y + (xy) = -y(x-1) +(xy)$, so $y + (xy)$ is not in $A -p$. Very sorry for the confusing notation.